# Random crash then "a disk read error has occurred"

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, hardware-failure

So out of the blue today when my computer was tabbed out of a game things got laggy and my computer crashed with a scrambled corrupt version of my screen making me think it was the GPU overheating. However when I turned my computer off then back on I got an "a disk read error has occurred" error message. I looked at the HDD name in my clickBIOS2 and it had a scrambled corrupt looking name.

Anyway fast forward to now I am installing windows onto my second drive to attempt to recover some data. Considering I haven't had previous problems with this drive do you think it has failed? Should I carry on using it for my system when and if I can format it and finally do you think I will be able to RMA this drive?

Comment: You can use a tool like GSmartControl to read internal statistics and health data from the HD and also to let the HD do a self test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to find out the extent of the problem.  This could be just a few bad sectors and in that case there is no need to panic.

google and download mhdd
make a bootable cd from the iso.
scan the whole hard drive and see how many errors it finds.

There is a chance you might have to go into the BIOS and change the hard drive from AHCI or RAID into IDE or EIDE mode if your hard drive is not detected.

I use the rule of thumb if it takes longer than 24 hours to complete you have to many errors.

If the test comes back with a small number of errors a simple

chkdsk /R c:

will do the trick.

However, you should back up your data if you have not already.
Also you should start planning on getting a new hard drive within a year or less depending on the total number of errors.

If you hard drive warranty is nearly out use it while you got it.
If you are still within your warranty period and have not abused the hard drive getting an RMA should not be an issue.

Comment: Thank you very much! I burnt mhdd onto a cd but couldn't get the drive to show up and my bios for some reason doesn't support Sata mode changing. Anyway I ran chkdsk on the drive after I installed windows on my second drive and it said if fixed a couple of hundred kb of corrupt sectors. I then burnt a windows repair cd to fix any system files that may have been remove, rebooted and I'm back in like normal again. Now I going to back up anyway but do you think this was a one off crash that happened to corrupt some system files stopping my from booting? should I still save some money for a drive?

Comment: @Toeb How old is the hard drive?  Bad sectors happen, but if the drive is less than 1yr old it is bad.  I would still start saving for a new drive.  FYI:  chkdsk can not **fix** bad sectors it can only hide them so they are never touched again.

Comment: I think the drive was probably gone a year old recently and I haven't had problems before so I think I will save the money and have it there so I can drop it on a new HDD in an emergency. Anyway Thank you so much for your help.